# What is the SVN best practice for storing source when developing and testing with IDEs?

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, ide

I do a fair amount of personal development on my computer and have used TortoiseSVN (I'm on windows) for web projects, but haven't used any version control for other languages. Anyways, soon I will be starting a decent sized C++ project and was going to try using SVN for it.

For web development, I normally just used notepad++ and it was really easy to manage it with SVN (just commit the whole source folder). However, for this project I will be using an IDE (most likely Eclipse CDT or Visual Studio) and was wondering what the best practice is to manage all of the IDE, project, and binary files. My guess was to make the IDE project outside of the version control, and just point to all of the source files into the SVN so all of the build and project files aren't committed. This way the only files in the SVN would be the .cpp and .h files.

However, if I wanted to switch to a new branch, then I would need to update the location of all of the source and headers to the new folder which seems like it would be a huge hassle.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to use a modern code control system and leave SVN in the last millenium. git or hg. The best SVN practice these days is to switch from it.
IDEs have plugins for them, and also for SVN, so there nothing to worry about.   If you mean branches SVN is definitely not your friend.

Comment: Well regardless of whether I use SVN or Git, the same problem still remains. Also, SVN seems to be better when it's just personal development on one computer

Comment: believe me, it is not better. By a far margin. but as I said before, don't worry about IDE support for any of them, it exists.

Comment: I realize there are plugins for IDE's, but I'd rather manage it myself so I'm not dependent on one IDE. And then lets say I used git, how would I set it up then?

Comment: we had some recent related discussions here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seem I misgot the aim of the question in the first round. Now I'm assuming what is asked really to what to put under source control and what not.

Well, naturally everything but temporary/transient files.

If you install GitExtensions, it right away has a feature to populate the .gitignore file. Certainly depending on language you adjust it. Sure, solution, project, make files belong under control. .USER files storing some IDE preferences do not. As both IDEs and source control is ubiquitously used the content is fairly separated for many years, and should be pretty obvious as you do it.

External dependencies normally also shall be in a repo, though choice shall be made in which one. Some store everything together, others keep one dependency repo, others separate repos per component -- all depends on actual components and workflow. And you can replace physical storage of deps by an info file with stable links to the used version. It may also be covered later on the first change in dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio, there is a plugin that manages your files for you. As long as the files are part of the project, then they will be put into source control by the plugin. See [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for plugin info. Note that the express versions of Visual Studio are not supported.

I am sure eclipse has a plugin for SVN as well.

Comment: I know many IDEs have it integrated, but I'd rather not use them. I prefer the flexibility of controlling it myself even if it's a little more work. Also, it allows me to switch IDEs easier if I choose

Comment: @user2443357 - If you manage it outside of the IDE, it could be a lot more work, depending on your files. For example, when adding a project to SVN, ankhsvn is smart enough to know not to include your output directories (binaries) as well as other files (such as those pesky VS .sou files) into source control. Also, you are not forced to exclusively use the integrated version control. I happen to use both (annkhsvn + tortoise) on my projects. You may or may not be able to do this in Eclipse.